# How to trigger select event for text anchor inside Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I am using treemap from google charts and I want to perform some actions when a user selects some node. I am using the 'select' listener from the charts api and it works fine if someone clicks on the node but not the text inside in the node (see jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/a93b9va3/ ).

```
 google.visualization.events.addListener(tree, 'select', 
                function() {alert('something selected!')});
```

How can I trigger a select event also when someone clicks on the text?

Answer (score 0):

Add this CSS

```
    #chart_div text {
        pointer-events: none;
    }
```